# sphinxSE Setselect

Tags: sphinx

Using SphinxApi , We have using following query for sphinxApi Setselect:

```
$cl->SetSelect ( "*, IF( IN(watching, 1) OR ordered=1, 1, 0) AS customFilter" );
```

Using SphinxQL:

```
select IF( IN(watching, 1) OR ordered=1, 1, 0) AS customFilter from indexname
```

Is that same thing how to using in SphinxSE ? 
Any one can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM indexname WHERE query = ';select=*, IF( IN(watching, 1) OR ordered=1, 1, 0) AS customFilter';
```

Of course customFilter must be defined as a column on the sphinx virtual table, if you want to see the value in your results

Comment: thanks, while executing the query with your instructions (Sphinx Version 2.0.4 and SphinxSE - 0.9.9), i am getting following error as "Data source error: unknown parameter 'select'". i have added customFilter field in virtual table also "Please help me out to fix this problem.